# How to get hash of a tagged release in Github CLI?

Tags: bash, git, github, github-cli

How can I get the hash of the latest release in Github CLI?

I am able to list the most recent release via the CLI with the following:

```bash
gh release list --limit 1
```

which gives me

```
v3.59.0  Latest  (v3.59.0)  about 1 day ago
```

But it doesn't give me the hash of that release.

How can I retrieve the hash with via the gh CLI tool or any other means?

Comment: If you have a local checkout, this should work: `git rev-list -n 1 "$(gh release list --limit 1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"`

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Thanks @jordanm that has done the trick